# Why it is impossible to access resources in a static way?

Tags: android, resources

I know now, that if I need to get a recource in some static function, I have to pass context or recources of the context there somehow - by parameter or through a static variable. But **why** is it neccessary? The id's of the resources **are** reachable in static surroundings, for example `R.string.some_my_stuff`. If I want a system resource, it is also visible there  through `Resources.getSystem().getString(android.string.some_common_stuff)`. But why can't I do something similar to get an **application** resource? The resource files are the usual static part of the sources.  Resources are **static** and **belong** to application. The classes of application belong to it in the same way and I **can** access their static parts in a static way.

Why can't I use resources in all the application in same static way, which would be the most natural, but have to access them through instance instead?

I am afraid, I do not understand something very important.

Please, don't repeat that I can't do it. I know it, on my honour. Please, explain why, or show me the way... Only that will cure me from my sadness :-) Thank you.

Comment: your resources belong to your application, which is a context. what you can do is have an application class that is a singleton and access your resources from there. also, how come you need resources in a place where you cannot access any context?

Comment: Note that you cannot get those resources which are not loaded by concern activities/views.

Comment: @njzk. 1. That I can reach needn't mean that I MUST reach for it. 2. In activity static final var definitions you can't reach for the context, but reading global constants from recourses would be natural to do right here.

Comment: Please read the FAQ to learn what suitable questions are for StackOverflow. Please take your rants elsewhere.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Here are enough question asking for explanation why something is so or so. It is not a question with the undefinite answer. Yes, the question is very hard and I hoped that some of great experts here will help... If the answer is not known to you and you are mad at me because of it... Then reread the FAQ yourself. rants = "To speak or write in an angry or violent manner". Please explain, where had you seen it? I think, you should be sorry for your behaviour.

Comment: @AVD. Of course, such resources as layout are connected to an appropriate activity. But What about values? Colours? Dimens? XML? And so on.

Comment: You wrote in an angry or violent manner, including lots of yelling, in the question and your comments. Hence, this is a rant. "It is not a question with the undefinite answer" -- sure it is. Or, more accurately, the half-dozen people on the planet who might be able to answer it (the developers who wrote that portion of Android) mostly don't monitor StackOverflow and are unlikely to respond to people WHO YELL AT THEM LIKE THIS. Hence, for all intents and purposes, your question is unanswerable by anyone in position to answer it.

Comment: Dear Commonsware, me and many other people had used SHIFT on Typewriters for stressing the words. Long before any blogs or Internet or even Arpanet appeared. I couldn't imagine that somebody can take this as shouting or yelling. Shouting in writing usually needs exclamation mark, as I was taught by my mother. I bring my excuses if I offended you or somebody else. So, if I use bold instead of shift, it would be acceptable, I hope? Or somebody will interpret it as a dangerous hissing? :-)

Comment: Please, how could a SHIFTed word in a conditional clause could be taken as shouting? Sorry, I can't edit comments.

Comment: @Gangnus Upper-case is canonically shouting in email/text messages/etc. and has been for some time. Emphasis has long-been denoted by asterisks/etc. even back when people like you and I were first starting on Usenet. While not as far back as when I started, [RFC 1855](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1855) (circa 1995, 15+ years ago) explicitly states caps look like you're shouting and symbols should be used for emphasis.

Comment: I see. I will try to control myself, but the problem is, that I am accustomed to take shift as stressing. And used that since my childhood. And my mother uses it so in her fairy-tales for about 60 years already. So, please, understand the difficulty of such change for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource IDs are unique per application, they are not unique over all application (including the Android system). E.g. there may be two different string in different applications which have the same ID, say 42.
Therefore yon may access only one application statically (every programmer must agree which one that is, its the Android system (there no choice, its the only one always installed)). For all the other application you must be able to tell the system which application's resources you want to access. You do this using the context.

Comment: +1. the second part of your message has an interesting thought. But IMHO, it is not the answer. The activity's instance context has access to the application resources. It is correct for every activity in the application. But their classes belong to the application, too. Why only activities' instances see the resources, but not the activities' classes? They **do not** belong to the Android system.

Comment: static information in the class is generated at compile time. But you cannot ID the application at compile time, because you cannot guarantee unique IDs at that moment. Only the instance of your application represented by the context (generated when the application is started) gives a unique ID, generated at this time by the Android system. To give you static access the launcher had to modify the code.

Comment: In my above comment replace "compile time" by "class loading time". This means the class loader would be able to inject information. However, it does not.

Comment: While classes are being loaded, resources are being loaded, too. Classes can be dependent on each other and teir loading takes it into account. So, there wouldn't be a technical problem to take resources info into classes info. I think, it is blocked because alllowing this could have some unpleasant effects. Or, purely historically - because layouts could really need contexts and it was extrapolated to other resources. But in the second variant a workaround would be surely possible, while in the first - it is principally impossible.