# How can I initialize this int as a constant?

Tags: java, android, constants, imagebutton, final

My software involves changing images a lot. Rather than look up the resource number repeatedly, I would like to create some constants to represent each image reference. Here are my attempts so far:

*This attempt produces a force close on start up.*

```
private final int EMPTY = getResources().getIdentifier("dotted_circle", "resId", "en.deco.android.livehud");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        .....
    }
```

*This Attempt returns an error "final variables may not be initialized". Removing final allows it to work.*

```
private final int EMPTY

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            EMPTY = getResources().getIdentifier("dotted_circle", "resId", "en.deco.android.livehud");
        }
```

Is using constants here a good idea in the first place?

Comment: I thought the whole point of constants was so you could not change the value?

Comment: I don't want to change the value. The image will retain the same id throughout the applications usage.

Comment: `final` fields must be set by the time your object is built, so you have to set them on the constructor. You can't do it on the declaration since your object is not ready yet, plus the methods there can throw exceptions that you'll never notice.

Comment: It is really strange. I Java tutorials and docs at Oracle I am sure I have seen the possibility to declare the field as final instance once and set value to it later. The only problem- you can't do it twice and you should check it. Haven't you done it twice, by chance?

Comment: @Gangus
Nope. I assumed the same thing, that I could set it once and no more.

Comment: And what version of Java have you set? It is a pity - it was my last hope.

Comment: @Gangnus From WP: "A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement. It need not be initialized at the point of declaration: this is called a "blank final" variable. A blank final instance variable of a class must be definitely assigned at the end of every constructor of the class in which it is declared (...)"

Comment: The most recent one, I lose track of the version numbers but I updated it within the last week.
It's a shame because the main time I'd like to use constants would be to replace chunky method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is using constants here a good idea in the first place?

No. It's better a routine that read the value from resources:

```
public class ImageUtils {

   private static int empty = -1;

   public static int getEmpty(Context context) {
        if(empty == -1)
          empty = context.getResources().getIdentifier("dotted_circle", "resId", "en.deco.android.livehud");

        return empty;
   }

}
```

Comment: This, just make sure the method caches the value instead of reading from a file every time.

Comment: What advantages does this have over merely removing 'final' from the int?

Comment: this is is static and can be invoked from everywhere

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to load resources into constants.

I had already made a search on the subject and asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848121/why-it-is-impossible-to-access-resources-in-a-static-way) here on it - No way.

Look at it so - they are already constants. so, you could you them i site, if effectivity is not a problem. Or load them into variables. It is sad, isn't it?

Comment: Would it be fine to just implement this as a regular/variable int?

Comment: Yes, that is how I use it myself. But I use it for complicated structures and seeing these pieces of code at Oracle I hoped that in easier cases I could use "final". Now you have killed, not, you have murdered that hope  :..(

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't work because you are trying to call methods of your class before it is constructed.  The second doesn't work because you are not initialization your final variable on construction.  (It needs to be done at the definition, or in the constructor).  Make your getResource operation a static method of another class (something like ResourceUtilities.getResources()) and that should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Create Application class. See example [here.](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/AndroidHelp/blob/master/AndroidHelp/src/com/base/App.java)
Then use it like this:

```
private final int EMPTY = App.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("dotted_circle", "resId", "en.deco.android.livehud");
```